# Problems with 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, intel, x86-16

I have to calculate the area of defined polygons which points (x,y) are stored in the stack, but I can't figure out why the code isn't working, could you help me?
The process is about calculating [(x-xo)(y+yo)]/2 with all of those points.

In this code I'm trying a simple polygon (area = 1) and not yet dividing by two because the sum is not always working, and I really don't know what is wrong. In the end it should give me (-2), but I don't seem to actually get this.

```
Soma = the final result
ContPt = number of points (x,y)
temp = just temporary variables




    mov soma, 0
        mov ax, 0
        push ax
        mov ax, 0
        push ax
        mov ax, 0
        push ax
        mov ax, 1
        push ax
        mov ax, 1
        push ax
        mov ax, 1
        push ax
        mov ax, 1
        push ax
        mov ax, 0
        push ax

        pop ax
        mov temp2, ax
        pop ax
        mov temp1, ax
        pop ax
        mov temp4, ax
        add ax, temp2
        pop bx
        mov temp3, bx
        sub bx, temp1
        mul bx
        add soma, ax

        mov cx, ContPt
        sub cx, '2'
    Lp: mov dx, temp4
        pop ax
        mov temp4, ax
        add ax, dx
        mov dx, temp3
        pop bx
        mov temp3, bx
        sub bx, dx
        mul bx
        add soma, ax
        loop Lp

        mov ax, temp2
        mov dx, temp4
        add ax, dx
        mov bx, temp1
        mov dx, temp3
        sub bx, dx
        mul bx
        add soma, ax
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do with all those pushes and pops at the beginning?

Comment: It looks like he is pushing (xi,yi) coordinate pairs on the stack to simulate the input conditions he's given.  Of course there is no way to tell how many points there are.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger and comment your code.

Comment: you're pushing and moving too much, the values are already in ax, no need to mov again and again. and `xor ax, ax`, `inc ax` are shorter

Comment: I'm doing what Gene said, and there are 4 points. Just forget about those pushs at the beggining.

Comment: Hint: For to write an imediate value into a memory location we have to specify how many bytes we want to access. Example: "mov word ptr[soma],0" for using MASM and "mov word[soma],0" for using NASM. Because without specifying the assembler do not know, if we want to access only one byte, a word, or a douple word of the memory location.

Comment: keep the data points in a memory structure. In consecutive words, assigned and allocated for that purpose, like:    point1  dw x1, y2; point2 dw x2, y2 ...    ; if having one label for each is necessary at all. I can imagine that it isn't, and a single label at begin of data would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're far away from a correct, let alone a good program.  First, there's nothing in your arguments on the stack to say how many points there are.  Second, you should code in a HLL and then translate, using the HLL for comments.  Third, you need to learn more about addressing modes and use the `bp` register to access items on the stack directly rather than popping them from memory and putting them back into other memory locations.

The HLL for polygon area is something like:

```
int n = 4; // number of points
int sum = 0;
for (int q = n - 1, p = 0; p < n; q = p++) 
  sum += pts[q].x * pts[p].y - pts[p].x * pts[q].y;
return sum / 2;
```

Now lay out the stack.  Assume that you've pushed arguments in this order:  `pts[0].x, pts[0].y, pts[1]x, pts[1].y, ... , pts[n-1].x, pts[n-1].y, n`.  Then you have

```
sp-2*n-4 -> pts[0].x
sp-2*n-2 -> pts[0].y
...   
sp-4     -> pts[n-1].x
sp-2     -> pts[n-1].y
sp       -> n
```

So we can access the points like an array by setting bp = sp - 2*n - 4

```
  mov bp, sp
  mov cx, [bp]      ; cx = n, loop counter
  mov si, cx        ; si = n
  shl si, 1         ; si = 2 * n
  neg si            ; si = -2 * n
  lea bp, [bp+si-4] ; bp = sp - 2*n - 4
  mov di, 0         ; di = p * 4 = 0, location of first point wrt bp
  neg si            ; si = 2 * n
  shl si, 1         ; si = 4 * n
  sub si, 4         ; si = q * 4 = (n-1) * 4, location of last point wrt bp
  xor dx, dx        ; dx = sum = 0
  jcxz done         ; Skip loop if counter is zero      
next:
  mov ax, [bp+si]   ; ax = pts[q].x
  imul [bp+di+2]    ; ax *= pts[p].y
  add dx, ax        ; sum += pts[q].x * pts[p].y
  mov ax, [bp+di]   ; ax = pts[p].x
  imul [bp+si+2]    ; ax *= pts[q].y
  sub dx, ax        ; sum -= pts[p].x * pts[q].y
  mov si, di        ; advance q
  add di, 4         ; advance p
  loop next         ; keep going until cx is zero
done:
  asr dx, 1         ; sum /= 2
  ; Here dx holds answer
```

I have no way of testing this.  I have not done 8086 assembly language for 25 years, but it ought to be close.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry about this code, it's just for college purposes and I'm totally new to this language. Also, it's out of context and I forgot people may not understand the main idea, but i'll try and comment the code next time.